# sum using group by not giving expected result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I need to sum values of one column using group by on another column and override the dataframe with those values

I have tried-

```
df.groupby('S/T name')['Age group (Years)Total Persons'].sum()
```

Dataframe to implement sum on -

```
S/T code        S/T name          city name         population
1                NSW            Greater sydney       1000
1                NSW            rest of nsw          100
1                NSW            rest of nsw          2000
2                Victoria       Geelong              1200
2                Victoria       Melbourne            1300
2                Victoria       Melbourne            1000
```

Required ouput-

```
S/T code        S/T name        population
1                NSW                3100
2                Victoria           3500
```

Comment: what result are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

**Solution 1**

```
grouped_df = df.groupby('S/T name')['population'].sum()
print(grouped_df)
```

The above code will group results by column `S/T name` and give the `sum` of `population` column.

**Solution 2**

```
grouped_df1 = df.groupby('S/T name').agg({'S/Tcode':'unique','population': 'sum'})
grouped_df1
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be summing on the wrong column in your example, switching to population would have got you most of the way:

```
df.groupby('S/T name')['population'].sum()
```

Since you want to retain the S/T code column though you can use [agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html#pandas-dataframe-agg). Calling sum on your population column and mean on your S/T code column:

```
df.groupby('S/T name').agg({'population': 'sum', 'S/T code': 'mean'})
```

Output:

```
S/T name        S/T code  population              
NSW              1        3100
Victoria         2        3500
```